# best practice on multi-client sql access architecture

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, architecture

I'm right now looking into planning a simple multi-client setup where each native .net client instance shall be able to connect to a SQL db.

However, my concern is the architecture. In case the setup grows to a couple hundred client connections, what would be the best architecture to start with?

The whole setup will stay in a closed network.

A: Implementing a handler service between the clients and SQL db to later better balance loads?

B: Directly connect the clients to the DB?

Very much looking forward to reading your thoughts and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be really reluctant to directly expose the db, that may make any db changes require updating clients. I would put a service in between (REST, SOAP whatever) then expose only the operations and objects you need. Then if you find you need to say denormalise some data for performance the service definition and client don't need to change.

This also means you can have logic on the server (other than sprocs), its always easier to update a server than multiple clients if you need to fix or improve something. Caching will work better too and help with db loads.

You may find yourself needing to get data from somewhere other than the DB, for example if you need good full text searching a common approach is to use Lucence for the searching and the retrieve the items found from the relational DB. Maybe you will need to get additional data from some other service or app. Again a server can do all this without the client having to know or care.

You also have a lot less db connections and they should be low latency as the service and db can be on the same subnet. I don't know how good your connectivity is going to be but something like REST with HTTP is probably going to be a lot more tolerant than a raw db query.

So I would go client -> server -> db.